# Can someone explain to me what this syntax mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was searching to find how to make the camera fit a game object and I found this answer:

[Change the size of camera to fit a GameObject in Unity/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013982/change-the-size-of-camera-to-fit-a-gameobject-in-unity-c) ,
and I don't understand this part

```
cam.orthographicSize = ((w > h * cam.aspect) ? (float)w / (float)cam.pixelWidth * cam.pixelHeight : h) / 2;
```

I want to understand how that part of the code works.

Comment: Is there anything about that statement you understand?  What part do you need explained?  Is it the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) that's confusing you?   `condition ? A : B`

Comment: Are you just asking what the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) is?

Answer (score 1):

if you dont understand `condition ? A : B`

maybe this will help you

```
if(w > h * cam.aspect){
  cam.orthographicSize = ((float)w / (float)cam.pixelWidth * cam.pixelHeight ) / 2
}
else{
  cam.orthographicSize = h / 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of breaking it down piece by piece. Let's see:

`cam.orthographicSize =`

`STEP 1: ((w > h * cam.aspect) ? (float)w / (float)cam.pixelWidth * cam.pixelHeight : h)`

`STEP 2: [STEP 1] / 2`

Step 1 divides into the following:

`STEP 1.1: h * cam.aspect (let's call this "JOHN")`

`STEP 1.2: (float)cam.pixelWidth * cam.pixelHeight (let's call this "WENDY")`

`STEP 1.3:` Ternary operator (it's just an IF else written in a fancy way)

```
IF w is greater than "JOHN" THEN
    RETURN (float)w / "WENDY"
ELSE
    RETURN h
```

At the end whatever comes from step 1, is divided in 2 (step 2). Here's more info about the [ternary operator](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/ternary-operator)